# How to access List of List of Beans in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, graphael

I'm using Raphael charts with JSF 2.1. I'm trying to draw a linechart which takes input for x-axis is an array of arrays and so is y-axis. My x-axis should contain timestamps(xvals in xhtml) and y-axis should be containing avgVal(avgbpsvals in xhtml). How can I access TBean instance variables like dt, avgVal in javascript? the ui:repeat only gives me result beans.

```
    Class InputBean{
    private List<List<TBean>> results;
    private List<TBean> result;
private String resultJSON;
    //getters and setters
private String getResultJSON(){
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.toJson(results);
}
    }

Class TBean{
private Timestamp dt;
private Long avgVal;
//getters and setters
}
```

In sample.xhtml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/raphael.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/g.raphael.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/g.line.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function() {
                    var r = Raphael("holder", 1000, 1000);
    var results = #{inputTablePlot.resultJSON};
 for(var i=0; i &lt; results.length; i++)
                {
                    for(var j=0; j &lt; results[i].length; j++)
                    {
                        alert("j : " + j);
                        alert("value: " + results[i][j].avgVal);
                    }
                }
                    var lines = r.linechart(40, 30, 900, 900, xvals,
                            avgbpsvals, {
                                smooth : true,
                                symbol : 'circle',
                                axis : "0 0 1 1"
                            });
                    };

    </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="holder" layout="block"></h:panelGroup>
    </h:body>
    </f:view>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can nest `<ui:repeat>`. Did you try it?

Comment: updated code; I tried adding <ui:repeat> on the returned values of first <ui:repeat> but it didn't work :(

Comment: Or even easier, instead of converting the `List<List<TBean>> results` to JSON in your Facelets code, do it in the managed bean using a JSON library like GSON or Jackson and save this in a `String` field that you will pass from the managed bean to your JavaScript.

Comment: updated code; Added GSON; That's awesome, Thanks for the help! I could print my values in console (output ::[[{date1,val1},{date2,val2}][{date3,val3},{date4,val4}]]); I just have one more doubt, how can I access the returned objects i.e, if I have to get date1, date2 ?

Comment: updated code, It works perfectly now! thank you; for(var i=0; i &lt; results.length; i++)
       {
           for(var j=0; j &lt; results[i].length; j++)
           {
               alert("j : " + j);
               alert("value: " + results[i][j].avgVal);
           }
       }